# Диалог выбора цвета на Android

Tags: android, qt

Как дать пользователю выбрать цвет в Android? Стандартный класс `QColorDialog` не подходит тем, что он большой и в экран смартфона не помещается, в нем невозможно сделать другие надписи, и он не ведет себя как модальное окно на Android. Можно ли как-то настроить этот класс или использовать какой-то другой класс, чтобы сделать диалог выбора цвета, пригодный для мобильных устройств?

Comment: Библиотеки не искал похожие?

Comment: Использовать что-то вместо Qt?

Comment: Я использовал 3 SeekBar, отвечающие соответственно за содержание красного, синего и зелёного оттенков в цвете, и 1 TextView с известными размерами, у которого менял цвет по изменении SeekBar

Answer (score 0):

Есть хорошая библиотека https://github.com/yukuku/ambilwarna

[image: скриншот]

Используется очень просто:

```
int initialColor = 0xff000000; // цвет, который выйдет при вызове диалога.

    AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(this, initialColor, new OnAmbilWarnaListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {
            // int color - Это цвет который выбрал пользователь.
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {
            // пользователь отменил выбор цвета
        }

    dialog.show();
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, что этот метод не пойдет из-за использования Qt